# Extracting text between html tags

Tags: sql, postgresql

I used postgres

I have this query

```
 SELECT 
 row_number() OVER (ORDER BY corresp.ID_CORRESP) as rNUM ,
 transfers.id_transfer AS TRANSFER_ID_TRANSFER, 
 corresp.id_corresp as  ID_CORRESP, 
 corresp.ORDERNBR_CORRESP as  ORDERNBR_CORRESP, 
 transfers.text_transfer AS TEXT 
FROM Transfers transfers 
 left outer join correspondence corresp  on corresp.id_corresp = transfers.id_corresp 
 left outer join tranf_corresp_tocc_employee on  tranf_corresp_tocc_employee.id_transfer = transfers.id_transfer
 left outer join employee on tranf_corresp_tocc_employee.id_employe = employee.id_employe 
 left outer join employee_lang on employee.id_employe = employee_lang.id_employe
 left outer join unit on employee.id_unit = unit.id_unit 
 left outer join unit_lang on unit_lang.id_unit =unit.id_unit
 left outer join action on action.id_action = transfers.id_action  
 left outer join action_lang on action_lang.id_action = action.id_action 
 WHERE transfers.status_transfer ='P'
```

but the problem that **transfers.text_transfer AS TEXT**  return this kind of result

```
<div align="right"><font color="3366FF"><b><font size="3">it's&nbsp;test</font></b></font></div>
```

I search the way to extract correct data from this result meaning extract `it's test`

so I want to add in my query same code to extract data from html tag ,  I think that I should use this function **REGEXP_REPLACE**

**Updated :**

when I try to run this query

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

I have this error :

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/plperl.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


********** Error **********

ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/plperl.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
SQL state: 58P01
```

I have plperl.dll under  C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib

**updated**

I try to use another way with this example :

```
CREATE FUNCTION testFunction
(@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
```

but I have this error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 2: (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "@"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 31
```

Comment: Please read the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Darn you @IgorRomanchenko, I was posting the same thing! Anyway. Do you want to PARSE the html or do you want to STRIP the html tags?

Comment: So the answer is use a specialized HTML parser in your client

Comment: That example function isn't even from PostgreSQL, it's from some other RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the database, use a PL/Perl, PL/Python, or similar tool that does proper HTML stripping.

For example, if you install `HTML::Strip` from CPAN or the `libperl-html-strip`  (Debian/ubuntu) or `perl-HTML-Strip` (Fedora/RHEL) package:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION striphtml(html text) RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plperlu
AS $$
use strict; use warnings; use 5.10.1;
use HTML::Strip;

my $hs = HTML::Strip->new(decode_entities => 1);
my $stripped = $hs->parse($_[0]);
$hs->eof;
return $stripped;
$$;
```

then:

```
regress=> SELECT striphtml('<div align="right"><font color="3366FF"><b><font size="3">it''s&nbsp;test</font></b></font></div>');
 striphtml 
-----------
 it's test
(1 row)
```

or you could use [`HTML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) to do it more cleanly.

There are *many* other alternatives. Pick an existing one and use it.

Comment: I have error when I try to install plperlu,   I have updated my question

Comment: On windows you must install a suitable perl too.

Comment: I have problem to install plperlu on windows  , I try with another way without success,  I have updated my question

Comment: @franco Well, I just used plperl as one example. But it's not hard to  set up. You just have to install the correct Perl runtime. See the documentation for the Windows installer for details. If you're stuck ask on the EnterpriseDB forums or post a new question here.